# Get Root Domain Name and subdomain Of Website using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dns

I am using this function code

```
public function getRootDomain($domain)
{
$domain = explode('.', $domain);

$tld = array_pop($domain);
$name = array_pop($domain);

$domain = "$name.$tld";

return $domain;
}
```

And the output i get is something like example.com
but i want to show m.example.com or www.example.com
Help related this ..thankx

Comment: What is the input string?

Comment: $domain = "http://ads.appricart.com/tutorials.php";

Comment: See John Conde's answer then. It should work for you. If it does, remember to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/parse_url). You would want the `host`:

```
<?php
$url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';

// Prior to 5.4.7 this would show the path as "//www.example.com/path"
var_dump(parse_url($url));
?>
The above example will output:
array(3) {
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/path"
  ["query"]=>
  string(17) "googleguy=googley"
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
public function getRootDomain($domain)
{
    $parts = parse_url($domain);
    return $parts['host'];
}
```

If you're using PHP 5.4+:

```
public function getRootDomain($domain)
{
    return parse_url($domain)['host'];
}
```